# JavaScript submit not working Django From

Tags: javascript, python, django, forms

I have a simple form that uses `JavaScript` to validate and submit the form using `POST` to the database.

The script works for 2 forms but won't submit for other forms for some reason and I can't work out why. I've even copied the existing form and JS replaced it with new names and it still doesn't work and I cannot figure out why. I've tried to debug, but I'm getting `http200` for every request so not throwing any errors that I can see.

Working version:

```
var investor_form = document.getElementById("add-investor");
investor_form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (validated(this)) {
        this.classList.add("was-validated");
        var i_name = document.getElementById("investor-name").value;
        var i_website = document.getElementById("investor-website").value;
        var i_portfolio = document.getElementById("investor-portfolio").value;
        var i_comment = document.getElementById("ckeditor-classic").value;
        const csrftoken = document.getElementsByName("csrfmiddlewaretoken")[0].value;

        const formdata = new FormData();

        formdata.append("investor_name", i_name);
        formdata.append("investor_website", i_website);
        formdata.append("investor_portfolio", i_portfolio);
        formdata.append("investor_comment", i_comment);

        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "/apps/add_investor");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        xhr.send(formdata);
        xhr.onload = () => {
            window.location.reload();
        };
    }
})

// Form validation 
function validated(form) {
    console.log(form)

    var i_name = document.getElementById("investor-name");
    var i_website = document.getElementById("investor-website");
    var i_portfolio = document.getElementById("investor-portfolio");

    i_name_value = i_name.value.trim();
    i_website_value = i_website.value.trim();
    i_portfolio_value = i_portfolio.value.trim();

    if (i_name_value === "") {
        message = "Please fill investor name field"
        setErrorFor(i_name, message);
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(i_name)
    }

    if (i_website_value === "") {
        message = "Please fill investor website field"
        setErrorFor(i_website, message);
    } else if (!isUrl(i_website_value)) {
        message = "Website is not valid"
        setErrorFor(i_website, message);
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(i_website)
    }

    if (i_portfolio_value === "") {
        message = "Please fill investor portfolio field"
        setErrorFor(i_portfolio, message);
    } else if (!isUrl(i_portfolio_value)) {
        message = "Porfolio is not valid"
        setErrorFor(i_portfolio, message);
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(i_portfolio)
        return true;
    }
}


//  For Display Eroor
function setErrorFor(element, message) {
    element.classList.remove('is-valid');
    element.classList.add('is-invalid');
    parent = element.parentNode;
    for (var i = 0; i < parent.childNodes.length; i++) {
        if (parent.childNodes[i].className == "invalid-feedback") {
            notes = parent.childNodes[i];
            notes.innerHTML = message;
            break;
        }
    }
}

// For success Message
function setSuccessFor(element) {
    element.classList.remove('is-invalid');
    element.classList.add('is-valid');
}

// Check URL Pattern 
function isUrl(url) {
    var re = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;
    return re.test(url)
}
```

Non-working version with name changes

```
//  Project Form submit
var project_form = document.getElementById("add-project");
project_form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (validated(this)) {
        this.classList.add("was-validated");
        var i_name = document.getElementById("project-name").value;
        var i_website = document.getElementById("project-website").value;
        var i_comment = document.getElementById("ckeditor-classic").value;
        const csrftoken = document.getElementsByName("csrfmiddlewaretoken")[0].value;

        const formdata = new FormData();

        formdata.append("project_name", i_name);
        formdata.append("project-website", i_website);
        formdata.append("project_comment", i_comment);

        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "/apps/add_project");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        xhr.send(formdata);
        xhr.onload = () => {
            window.location.reload();
        };
    }
})

// Form validation 
function validated(form) {
    console.log(form)

    var i_name = document.getElementById("project-name");
    var i_website = document.getElementById("project-website");


    i_name_value = i_name.value.trim();
    i_website_value = i_website.value.trim();


    if (i_name_value === "") {
        message = "Please fill project name field"
        setErrorFor(i_name, message);
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(i_name)
    }

    if (i_website_value === "") {
        message = "Please fill project website field"
        setErrorFor(i_website, message);
    } else if (!isUrl(i_website_value)) {
        message = "Website is not valid"
        setErrorFor(i_website, message);
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(i_website)
        return true;
    }
}


//  For Display Eroor
function setErrorFor(element, message) {
    element.classList.remove('is-valid');
    element.classList.add('is-invalid');
    parent = element.parentNode;
    for (var i = 0; i < parent.childNodes.length; i++) {
        if (parent.childNodes[i].className == "invalid-feedback") {
            notes = parent.childNodes[i];
            notes.innerHTML = message;
            break;
        }
    }
}

// For success Message
function setSuccessFor(element) {
    element.classList.remove('is-invalid');
    element.classList.add('is-valid');
}

// Check URL Pattern 
function isUrl(url) {
    var re = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;
    return re.test(url)
}
```

I've just done a find and replace for `investor` to `project` and then I have created copies of the forms/model/views/urls etc and updated to `project`

but it just won't update the database.

If I go into Django admin I can manually add the records, so I know the migration has worked.

response when clicking submit

```
[30/Oct/2021 20:10:36] "GET /apps/add_project HTTP/1.1" 200 32840
[30/Oct/2021 20:10:59] "POST /apps/add_project HTTP/1.1" 200 59
[30/Oct/2021 20:10:59] "GET /apps/add_project HTTP/1.1" 200 32840
```

views.py

```
class addProjectView(View):
    template_name = 'pages/add_project.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = addProjectForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            data = {"success": "successfully added"}
        else:
            data = {"error": form.errors}
        return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)


add_project_view = addProjectView.as_view()
```

Models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    project_website = models.URLField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    project_comment = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.project_name)
```

Forms.py

```
class addProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(addProjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = '__all__'
```

form html add_project.html

```
{% extends 'partials/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block head_title%}
<title>Add Project | Dashboard</title>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="main-content">

    <div class="page-content">
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <!-- start page title -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="page-title-box d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                        <h4 class="mb-sm-0 font-size-50">Add Project</h4>
                        <div class="page-title-right">
                            <ol class="breadcrumb m-0">
                                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="javascript: void(0);">Pages</a></li>
                                <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Project</li>
                            </ol>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end page title -->
        </div> <!-- container-fluid -->
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <form class="needs-validation" id="add-project" novalidate method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return false;">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label class="form-label" for="project-name-label">Project Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="project-name" placeholder="Project Name">
                        <div class="valid-feedback">
                            Looks good!
                        </div>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            Please fill project name.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="project-url-input" class="form-label">Project Website</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="url" placeholder="https://example.com" id="project-website">
                        <div class="valid-feedback">
                            Looks good!
                        </div>
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            Please provide a valid web address.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Comments</h4>
                            <p class="card-title-desc">Please add any comments or notes</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <textarea id="ckeditor-classic"></textarea><br>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </form>

        <!-- end col -->
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="toastMessage" hidden></button>
    <div class="position-fixed top-0 end-0 p-3" style="z-index: 11">
        <div class="toast align-items-right text-white bg-primary border-0" id="toast-message" role="alert"
            aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
            <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="toast-body">
                    Successfully added Project!
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white me-2 m-auto" data-bs-dismiss="toast"
                    aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- End Page-content -->
    {% endblock %}
    {% block extra_js %}
    <!-- ckeditor -->
    <script src="{% static 'libs/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/build/ckeditor.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- init js -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/pages/form-editor.init.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- pristine js -->
    <script src="{% static 'libs/pristinejs/dist/pristine.min.js' %}"></script>

    <!-- form validation and XHR call -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/pages/project.init.js' %}"></script>

    {% endblock %}
```

Any ideas why its not working or how I can debug this?

Thanks

Comment: there is no solution without minimal working code which we could run to see problem

Comment: I've added the code from the different python files. Does this help. If not could you let me know what the minimal working code i need to supply?

Comment: `formdata.append("project-website", i_website);` is incorrect in js code fix it.
correct key is`"project_website"`

Comment: OMG. Thanks so much. I can't believe that was all it was. I've looked over that code about 100 times and just didn't see the typo.